# Found a post that completely broke SO formatting

Tags: support, questions, code-formatting

Consider [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9792829); more specifically, [its first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9792829/1). The post in question dates from March 2012.

The OP formatted his code by explicitly writing `<code>` markup. Somehow, the way he used it in combination with lists and code markup (4 spaces), it completely broke the rest of the post formatting:

- The tags are not written with the correct font and are not correctly aligned.
- The blue-background panel showing the username is also not using the correct font and has huge vertical space.
- There are white spaces (that can be selected) *below* tags.

Note that it broke only this post and the answer was correctly formatted. I have since edited the post to have a proper formatting.

The problem is probably due to lack of `<pre>` when formatting multiple lines of code but I wouldn't have guessed that something like this could be done.

Can something be done to fix the resulting layout in a case like this?

Comment: _"Can something be done to fix the resulting layout in a case like this?"_ Edit??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But it makes you wonder what other marvelous things you can do, if someone were to do this intentionally

Comment: In order to truly fix this, we'd have to actually parse the HTML that users manually enter, which is a lot of effort and probably not at all worth it to catch edge cases like this.

Comment: @Tunaki What do you mean? Cause page issues? HTML is sanitised

Comment: @Tim Yes, I am talking about layout issues

Comment: @Tunaki Like...? That's not an issue, html is sanitized / blocked *really* carefully and is limited to the question div.

Comment: Isn't this something that used to be possible but no longer is because something was fixed and there's only a couple of old revisions that work weirdly? I can't remember

Comment: ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: Come on @j08691, if you're gonna copy/paste at least give credit to bobince. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/242

Comment: @DavidHAust Credit is always due. But in this case, if you don't know _that answer_ by bobince then you are not a true StackOverflow user :-PP

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Posts are written in Markdown, but what we see is a cached HTML version of what was parsed at the moment that the post was created. Presumably, in March 2012, there was a bug in the Markdown parser that cached a broken HTML version.

This [kind of thing happens from time to time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165100/278654) and the solution is to edit the old broken posts, as you did, to get the proper rendered version. The devs try to auto-detect those affected posts, but some of them will be left behind.

There's a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260776/warn-if-the-generated-preview-html-is-different-from-the-cached-html-when-starti) to detect this kind of issue when a post is being edited and the rendered HTML is different from the cached one. Also, another [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288611/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-deliver-answers-as-markdown-and-let-the-client-render) has suggested to render Markdown on the fly instead of using a cached version, but the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288614/1476885) explains quite well why this is not a good idea.